Use dynamic list in WHERE clause
I am trying to combine some data in MS SQL, but I am struggling to do this properly.
In one query, I am selecting projects that meet certain criteria.
E.G.:
SELECT
FROM PROJECTS
WHERE STATUS IS ACTIVE

And in a second query I am selecting GL transactions for all projects that were found by the first query.
E.G.:
SELECT
FROM GL
WHERE PROJECT ID = (SEE LIST)

How do I combine this in one query?

You can use either a JOIN or a WHERE ... IN clause:
SELECT GL.*
FROM GL
JOIN PROJECTS ON GL.ProjectID = PROJECTS.ProjectID
WHERE PROJECTS.Status = 'Active';

or
SELECT *
FROM GL
WHERE ProjectID IN (
    SELECT ProjectID
    FROM PROJECTS
    WHERE Status = 'Active'
);

